# Get dict value for key only if it is present

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and I am stuck with this question. I'd be grateful if someone could help.
Thanks in advance!

Write a function `key_checker` that takes as input a dictionary and a possible key.
The function should return `"This key is not in the dictionary"` if the key is not in the dictionary, or the `(key, value)` pair if the key is in the dictionary.

Comment: Have you tried solving it yet? If so, please paste your attempts

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not here to write code for you, just to help if needed (answering specific problem). Can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: You forgot to tell us how you want us to help.   /  You forgot to tell us what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Has your question been addressed? If so, you can help everyone—you, the respondents, and the community—by marking the correct answer using the checkbox beside it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `in`:

```
if key in dictionary:
```

So, your function would be:

```
def key_checker(dictionary, key):
    return key in dictionary
```

Example of how to use function:

```
basket = {'apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana'}
if key_checker(basket, 'pear'):
    print "The pear is in the basket"
else:
    print "Nooo pears!"
```

Comment: _if key in dictionary_ is _True_/_False_, wrapping it under if is _if_ is redundant and wastefull

Comment: @volcano Sorry, I'll edit :)

Comment: @volcano Fixed. Why all the down-votes :(

Comment: I am not speedy Gonzales :), While I removed downvote, I would like to point out that wrapping _in_ into a function is not a good idea too - you add overhead  of a function call to a simple operation, which is ... still redundant. There's also _dict.get_ method...

Comment: @volcano I wouldn't wrap it in a function, but the question says "Write a function `key_checker`"

Answer (score 0):

Exception-handling is faster than `if`-statements.

```
def key_checker(dict_, key):
    try:
        return key, dict_[key]
    except KeyError:
        return "This key is not in the dictionary"
```